# Banco de dados em não reflete mudanças na mesma activity

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite3

Estou tentando atualizar a base de dados em minha aplicação. Tentando simular um possível erro em produção intencionalmente eu dou um `DROP` em uma tabela, e logo em seguida faço um `SELECT` na mesma tabela e funciona. Ao mudar de *Activity* o mesmo procedimento é realizado, mas dessa vez o erro acontece.

Os seguintes passo são realizados:

1. Carrega o `LoadScreenActivity`
2. Efetua o `onUpgrade()`, se necessário, que copia a base nova do assets.
3. Caso `onUpgrade()` seja chamado executa-se o `procedimento()` para verificar se a base de dados está corrompida, como não achei uma forma de corromper a base para poder utilizar o `PRAGMA integrity_check`, então eu deleto a tabela mensagens apenas para simular o erro.
4. Chamo o `testar()` para verificar a integridade da base de dados.

   ```
   public boolean procedimento() {
       (...)
       database.execSQL("DROP TABLE mensagens");
       return testar();    
   }

   public boolean testar() {
       try {
           database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mensagens ORDER BY RANDOM()", new String[]{});
           return true;
       catch(Exception e){
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

Quando inicio a próxima *Activity* (no caso a `MainActivity`) e efetuo o mesmo `SELECT`...

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: mensagens: , while compiling: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mensagens ORDER BY RANDOM()

Por que o erro não acontece imediatamente na mesma *Activity*?

Answer (score 3):

Você está capturando a exceção no método `testar()` e retornando `false`. Com isso, o seu `SELECT` pode estar falhando mas a execução do programa não é interrompida e nenhuma mensagem de erro é exibida.

Comment: desculpe, mas o exemplo não está completo!
o negócio é que NUNCA da erro, nunca cai no Exception.

Comment: Esse código é executado dentro de `onUpgrade()`? Parece ser um problema com transações.

Comment: Durante, mas não dentro. É Executando logo após efetuar onUpgrade()

Comment: Desculpe, mas para mim ficou vago se está executando dentro de onUpgrade ou não. Por favor esclareça, de preferência incluindo o trecho relevante do `onUpgrade()` e o trecho que chama `procedimento()`.

Comment: Editei o texto @Piovezan veja se ficou mais claro. Obrigado!

Comment: Sei que deve ser o mesmo, mas mostre o código do segundo select... você chama `testar()` novamente?

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente ele está executando o `SELECT` antes de realizar o `COMMIT` na base de dados e, por isso, pega dados fantasmas. Quando ele faz o update na aplicação o banco é "comitado", porque a aplicação encerra a conexão com o banco e faz um auto-commit. Um `database.commit()` depois do `DROP` deve resolver o problema.

Comment: `DROP TABLE` é um comando DDL e não precisa de `commit()`.